# Plotting a 4d surface in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have data like:

```
x= [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000]
y = [8000, 6000, 4000, 2000, 5000, 460, 9000, 10000, 7000, 1000]
z1 = [0.058291129094573499, 0.058492463077565976, 0.057443040421411858, 0.057067449776274287, 0.057925625904860105, 0.05913730975122948, 0.058948907935401647, 0.057011876657602774, 0.057593608665131198, 0.058617625560861128]

z2 = [5.672484874725342, 5.43212890625, 5.274526119232178, 4.8752758502960205, 5.396219968795776, 4.534106016159058, 5.5845911502838135, 5.4695069789886475, 5.5511040687561035, 4.820451974868774]
```

Now, I am plotting two surface plots like following:

```
ax1.plot_trisurf(x,y,z1,linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
ax1.plot_trisurf(x,y,z2,linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
```

I was wondering if instead of these two 3d plots.. I can depict these two in one 4d plot and fourth dimension z2 being color gradient?
But I am not able to figure it out?

How do I do this in matplotlib?

Comment: Your `x` values are all equal, so couldn't you just omit this dimension?